# How to name a variable: numItems or itemCount?

Tags: naming-conventions

What is the right way to name a variable

```
int numItems;
```

vs.

```
int itemCount;
```

or constant:

```
public static final int MAX_NUM_ITEMS = 64;
```

vs.

```
public static final int MAX_ITEM_COUNT = 64;
```

Comment: Any time you're about to ask a question about the "right" way to do something, stop and consider whether it's merely a subjective, aesthetic preference. This certainly qualifies. It *absolutely doesn't matter*. Pick one that you like and stick with it.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I agree with that general rule -- but there is a difference in this case between "num" and "count". See below.

Comment: @Andy: I mean, sure. I even agree with you and Steve. But come on, that hardly justifies this question...

Comment: Sorry to come here late but this question should be closed. It is opinion-based

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Naming conventions for "number of foos" variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742650/naming-conventions-for-number-of-foos-variables)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731025/api-c-sharp-method-naming-convention-getpagecount-or-gettotalpages/14731102#14731102

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In "Code Complete," Steve McConnell notes that "Number" is ambiguous. It could be a count, or an index, or some other number.

> "But, because using Number so often
>   creates confusion, it's probably best
>   to sidestep the whole issue by using
>   *Count* to refer to a total number of sales and *Index* to refer to a
>   specific sale."

Comment: In volume 2, the quote is: > But, because using Num so often creates confusion, it’s probably best to side-step the whole issue by using Count or Total to refer to a total number of customers and Index to refer to a specific customer.

Comment: `Num` is indeed ambiguous but `numberOf` isn't. But `numberOf` is too long compared to a simple `count`

Answer (score 8):

item_count or itemCount  (there's a religious war brewing there, though)

Answer (score 4):

For Java I would use `itemCount` and `MAX_ITEM_COUNT`. For Ruby, `item_count` and `MAX_ITEM_COUNT`. I tend not to use names that can be interpreted wrongly (`numItems` may be a shortcut for `numerate_items` or `number_of_items`), hence my choice. Whatever you decide, use it constantly.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of personal preference, just make sure you are consistent throughout your code. If you're working with others check what's been done in existing code.

For the constant I would find `MAX_ITEMS` more logical than `MAX_NUM_ITEMS` or similar, it just sounds better to me.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on you. The two types of naming conventions are
camelCase and snake_case

As you can identify from the naming, camel case has one small letter in the initial part of the variable followed by the Capital words

Eg itemCount.

snake case is a continuous word with an underscore ' _ ' in between the words
Eg item_count

As far as the naming is concerned, numItems is quite confusing for others to read. But itemCount is a good name for a counter variable

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering about this question too, and thought it interesting in all these answers that no one said just `items`, but I can see that would be a bad name perhaps if it's in a codebase that has objects or arrays, but maybe okay as like a field name in SQL.

But one downside I just realized to going with something like `numItems` is that if you have multiple similar fields and use anything with intellisense or autocomplete, there's a risk of accidentally using the wrong field, whereas `item_count` begins with the thing you're counting.