# API: C# method naming convention: GetPageCount or GetTotalPages

Tags: c#, api, naming-conventions

I have an Interface `IPager`

```
public interface IPager
{
    int RecordCount { get; }
    int PageNumber { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
}

public static class PagerExtensions
{
    public static int GetPageCount(this IPager pager)
    {
        var totalPages = pager.RecordCount / pager.PageSize;
        if (pager.RecordCount % pager.PageSize > 0)
            totalPages += 1;
        return totalPages;
    }
}
```

Does `GetTotalPages` sound more conventional than `GetPageCount`?

Comment: That's subjective. Both are fine, choose the one you like more.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That is why I am asking the question: which makes more sense incase I have a new developer taking over a project! some explainations below make alot sense

Comment: I agree, the explanations make sense, still, all of them are subjective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me GetPageCount sounds better because it is closer to usual usage of code like `x.Count`  or `x.Count()` for the Linq extension.

And so, it clearly explains itself. `Get` - as in, return something. `Page` - the variable in question, and `Count` - as in the method who's return value is returned when applied to the variable in question.

Comment: So you'd put the word "Get" in front of every method that returns something? I'm not sure that adds much value... Math.GetMax(...) rather than Math.Max(...) for example? I'd just call it PageCount(). But I guess it's a matter of personal preference!

Answer (score 4):

In general: chose the most meaningful name.

In this case i would use `GetPageCount` since it's self-describing and also implies the type `int` unlike `GetTotalPages`  which could also return something like `IEnumerable<Page>`.

`GetPageCount` also follows this order:

- is it a getter/setter? -> Get
- what is get/set in general? -> Page
- what is get/set in particular? -> Count

This order makes it easier to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd go for just PageCount(). The "Get" prefix is really just noise.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I agree if it's just a property.If it's an _expensive_ method i would stay with `Get...`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply `Count()`?

You have extended something which implements `IPager`, the method perhaps doesn't need to extend page any further.

In the case of `List<T>` you get `Count` not `GetTCount()`.

It's personal preference really. What if you implement your `IPager` `interface` into a different type which isn't actually a `Page`?

Answer (score 1):

Code should be "self documenting" so using any name that is descriptive of what it does is fine. So long as the next guy that comes along understands what you were thinking without going through 1000 pages of documentation, you did your job.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think there's much of a difference. Use whatever you or your company prefers.